# Intent for drawing with finger?

Tags: android, android-intent

A lot of Android apps allow the user to draw on the screen.

My app is a rich content editor, I want to allow the user to insert images:

- From the gallery (images that exist already)
- Using a camera app
- Using a drawing app ← My question is about this one

Is there a "standard" intent for drawing apps?
Or at least an intent that is implemented by a majority of drawing apps?

I checked:

- [IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/135): Starts the camera, different purpose I think. Or is it usually construed by drawing apps makers?
- [GET_CONTENT](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/69): Extremely broad, but I will use it if I find nothing better.

Comment: Better make it yourself, i think there is no same default one on all android platform (at least on 2.1, 2.3 what I have).

Comment: @Tom: Make a drawing tool myself? Hum... I would like to avoid that, as it won't be as good as the drawing app that each user loves... and people who don't have drawing apps won't need this feature anyway, so better not make my app fatter.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [OpenIntents intent-database](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable) and not finding any intent, I'd say: No there is no publicly shared Intent for drawing, yet.